# Show that $M$ is the midpoint of $JI$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

*$H$ is the **orthocenter** of $\triangle ABC$

[image]

I don't even know where to start, it appears that point $E$ has nothing too special about it, line $LI$ is too mysterious to me, I couldn't turn it into a radical axis or any convenient polar w.r.t some circle. Projective geometry also doesn't seem to help except if we could use Pascal's theorem in a tricky way, perhaps with the symedian of $\triangle ABC$ but I'm not sure how to do it.

EDIT: well, here is a transcription of the problem since people asked me: $\triangle JIK$ is the orthic triangle of $\triangle ABC$ and $L$ is the reflection of $H$ with respect to $BC$. Show that line $BE$ bisects $JI$ ($E = (ABC) \cap LI \neq L$).

Comment: It is hilarious and embarrassing how I first interpreted your text. +1 to both the question and answer! I got idea of defining similar to $E$, $F=LJ \cap (ABC)$ and doing something in $\triangle LEF$ noting $EF \parallel IJ$, but couldn't see a way.

Comment: If you wish for a visual or geometric answer, I think this is too hard, there is a reason why math was invented; sometimes computations are the easy way!

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace this website has positively surprised me more than once in this regard. Let's wait.

Comment: As noted in an earlier comment, the analogous construction starting with $F=LJ \cap (ABC)$ also lands on $M$.  There are 4 more constructions starting from $B$ and $C$ that will also land on the other 2 midpoints.  If you replace $H$ with an arbitrary point $P$, the 6 analogous constructions will land on the cevian triangle corresponding to $P$, albeit not the midpoints, even if you replace $(ABC)$ with a circumconic. The proof of this would probably be projective, using angle-sin ratios, maybe cross ratios.  Which doesn't rule out a euclidean synthetic proof for this special case...

Comment: @brainjam projective geometry is welcomed

Comment: Hello my friend! Which is the source of this nice problem?! +1 (I've dropped an answer using projective geometry, that i may want to use for didactic purposes, and it is always a good practice to give credit to the original source...)

Comment: @dan_fulea a friend of mine sent me that image on Whatsapp, I will check the source with him

Comment: @dan_fulea the source is from a facebook greek page called "romantics of geometry", posted by user "Takis Chronopoulos", apparently they just got an answer similar to yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us have an initial picture for the given problem:

> The triangle $\Delta ABC$ is given, its orthocenter is $H$. We construct the ortic triangle $\Delta KIJ$. Let $L$ be the reflection of $H$ in $K$ (or w.r.t. $BC$). $LI$ intersects the circle for the second time in a point $E\ne L$. Let $M$ be the intersection $BE\cap IJ$.

[image: mse problem 4764581]

**Then:** $M$ is the mid point of the segment $IJ$.

---

*Intermezzo:* There is the notion of the **cross ratio** $r$ of four points on a **line**. It generalizes to the cross ratio $r_\circ$ of four points on a **circle**. As a reference i use Pamfilos' page [Complex_Cross_Ratio](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/Complex_Cross_Ratio.html).

> If $A,B,C,D$ are points of a circle, which project from some $X$ on the same circle on $A',B',C',D'$ on some line, then $r_\circ(A,B;C,D)=r(A',B';C',D')$.

We use this property in the proof to conclude in a few lines.

---

*Proof:*
Consider the points $F,G$ on the circumcircle $\odot(ABC)$ so that:

- $F\ne B$ is the second intersection point of $BI$ with the circumicrcle,
- $G\ne B$ is taken so that $BG\|IJ$, so $\widehat{GLA}=\widehat{GBA}=\widehat{IJA}=\hat C$, and $\overset\frown{BA}=\overset\frown{AG}$.

We need below $BHIF\|LG$ and $IJ\|GB$ to read the projections of the infinity points.

[image: mse problem 476481 application of cross ratio on a circle]

Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{MJ}{MI}
&=r(M,\infty;J,I)
\\
&=r_\circ(E,G;A,F)
&&\text{ projecting from $B$ the circumcircle on $IJ$,}
\\
&=r(I,\infty;H,F)
&&\text{ projecting from $L$ the circumcircle on $BHIF$,}
\\
&=\frac{IH}{IF}=1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, $\infty$ is in both cases the (one and the other) infinity point on the corresponding line involved in the cross ratio.

$\square$

Comment: Nice! $r_\circ(I,\infty;H,F)$ on the 2nd last line should be $r(I,\infty;H,F)$

Comment: @brainjam Oh yes, thanks, there was too much copy+paste at that late hour...

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume $\angle IBM =B_1$ and $\angle JBM= B_2.$

By the law of sines in $\triangle JIB,$ we have:

$$\frac{MI}{MJ}=\frac{BI}{BJ} \times \frac{\sin B_1}{\sin B_2}.  \ \  (*)$$

In $\triangle BEI,$ we have:

$$\frac {\sin B_1}{\sin \angle BEL}=\frac{\sin B_1}{\cos B}=\frac{EI}{BI} \implies \sin B_1= \cos B \times \frac{EI}{BI}.$$

In $\triangle AEB,$ we have:

$$\frac {\sin B_2}{\sin \angle AEB}=\frac{\sin B_2}{\sin C}=\frac{AE}{AB} \implies \sin B_2= \sin C \times \frac{AE}{AB}.$$

Now, having $\sin B_1$ and $\sin B_2$ along with $(*)$, we get:

$$\frac{MI}{MJ}=\frac{\cos B}{\sin C} \times \frac{EI}{AE}\times \frac{AB}{BJ}. $$

On the other hand, $\triangle AEI$ and $\triangle ICL$ are similar. As a result, $\frac{EI}{AE}=\frac{IC}{LC}.$

Therefore,
$$\frac{MI}{MJ}=\frac{\cos B}{\sin C} \times \frac{IC}{LC}\times \frac{AB}{BJ} \\ =\frac{\cos B}{\sin C}\times \frac {IC}{BJ} \times \frac{AB}{LC} \\ = \frac{\cos B}{\sin C} \times \frac{\cos C}{\cos B} \times \frac{\sin C}{\cos C}=1 \\ \implies MI=MJ. $$

---

**Remark:** $\frac {IC}{BJ}=\frac{\cos C}{\cos B}$ and $\frac{AB}{LC}=\frac{\sin C}{\cos C}$ need to be verified, which is not a hard task.